# How do I format all commits in a branch?

Tags: git, git-rewrite-history

I'd like to run an auto-formatting tool (e.g. Prettier, `go fmt`, `clang-format`, `terraform fmt` ...) on all commits in a branch. I could manually edit each commit in the branch using an interactive rebase (`git rebase -i`) but that is quite tedious if there are a lot of commits on the branch.

How do I automatically apply the auto-formatting to each commit in the branch?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `git rebase --exec` like so:

```bash
git rebase \
  --strategy-option=theirs \
  --exec '<formatting/linting command here>' \
  --exec 'git add `git show --name-only --pretty="" HEAD`' \
  --exec 'git commit --amend --no-edit' \
  <base branch, e.g. "main" or "master">
```

**Source:** https://blog.scottlogic.com/2019/03/04/retroactively-applying-prettier-to-existing-branches.html

**Note:** This is also possible using `git filter-branch --tree-filter` but that command is now [discouraged](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch#_warning) and produces a warning when invoked on the command-line. The suggested alternative [git-repo-filter](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo) cannot do this directly, but contains an example `lint-history`-command which is able to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with git-rebase(1) for formatting is that it can lead to merge
conflicts. Which are irrelevant: you are just normalizing all of the
commits, so there shouldn't be any real conflicts.

But what if every step of the rebase was run on the *snapshot* (the tree)?
Then the run of the previous step would not interfere with the current
step. So if the formatting changes consisted of for example:

- Use four-space indent instead of two-space
- Use one-arg-per-line for function calls on long lines
- Always add a space between operators

Then it seems that we should neither introduce textual conflicts nor any
logical conflicts.

And that's what the third-party git-branchless(1) tool does with [`git test fix`](https://github.com/arxanas/git-branchless/discussions/803):

```
git test fix --exec 'cargo fmt --all'
```

Or replace `cargo fmt --all` with some other formatting command that
formats all tracked files.